# Re read the message from high level consumer without restarting the high level consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I implemented the high level consumer code with manual offset in my local but I have one question to ask that if suppose if we do not commit the message is there any logic to read that message again without restarting the consumer again.I am able to get that message if I am restarting the consumer but how to get that without restarting the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka High level consumer(upto kafka 0.8.2) does not provide fine grained control over offsets.
Hence you can not go back and read the earlier offset ( without restarting).

In latest kafka release 0.9.0 they have updated consumer api. This new consumer api has an option to seek. Using the seek call you can seek to a particular offset at any point in time.

Comment: how to use seek using kafka consumer.Can u let me understand with a example.